Xunit moq contructor passing mock.Object thows method not found but works when null is passed instead
Im trying to create a XunitTest using moq,the class im trying to create a unit test has a constructor accepting two parameters ,to be more specefic,here is the class im trying to create a test for:
         private readonly CarValueServiceDbContext _dbContext;
         private readonly IUserGroupQueries _userGroupQueries;

         public CarQueries(CarValueServiceDbContext dbContext, IUserGroupQueries userGroupQueries)
         {
             _dbContext = dbContext;
             _userGroupQueries = userGroupQueries;
         }

in my test class im trying to do like this :
             [Fact]
         public async Task Get_PassTrue_ExpectedToGetOnlyMappedCars()
         {
             using (var dbContext = new CarValueServiceDbContext(_dbContextOptions))
             {
                  var _userGroupQueries=new   Mock<IUserGroupQueries>();
                 await dbContext.Car.AddRangeAsync(new Car { Name = "test", Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Comment = "hjhghfh" },
                                                    new Car {Name="Car1",Comment="comments"},
                                                    new Car { Name = "Car1", Comment = "comments",Id=Guid.NewGuid() });
                 await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

                 var rslt = new CarQueries(dbContext, 
    _userGroupQueries.Object);
                 var testedMethod=rslt.Get();

             }
         }

but when it reaches to this._userGroupQueries.Object it says :
   System.MissingMethodException : Method not found: 
  'System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilder 
   System.AppDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(System.Reflection.AssemblyName, 
   System.Reflection.Emit.AssemblyBuilderAccess)'.

but when i pass null it works,does anyone has any idea why it does not work ?

Is the CarQueries class internal? If so, you need to grant InternalsVisibleTo access to DynamicProxyGenAssembly2 so the types can be accessed to generate the mock.

@MartinCostello not really its Public

You define the variable var _userGroupQueries, but then you reference this._userGroupQueries (this). Is that intended?

@AstridE. sorry my bad when i was editing,updated

Are you positive the complaint is regarding _userGroupQueries.Object, not the call to rslt.Get()?

@AstridE. yes the thing is if i pass null it works ,but _userGroupQueries.Object is throwing the error

It may be not related to the code itself. Have you tried cleaning the solution and deleting old DLLs, if any? (ref. this SO post)

@AstridE. yes i have tried but still getting the same error,if i pass null it works,seems the constructor is the issue
